# Feign client unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot

I would like to know what is the best way to write unit tests in this context :

MyApi :

```
@RestController
public class MyApi{

    @Autowired
    MyAction myAction;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity addAction(@ResponseBody MyDto myDto){
        return myAction.addAction(myDto);
    }
}
```

MyAction :

```
@Service
public class MyAction{

    @Autowired
    private MyClient myClient;

    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponseDto> login(MyDto myDto{
        return ResponseEntity.ok(myClient.addClient(myDto));
    } 

}
```

For example, is it mandatory to add constructor ?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by this `is it mandatory to add constructor `?

Answer (score 1):

It's considered a good practice to use constructor injection, however if you don't want to use it you need to use `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`. It uses reflection and constructor is not required to be defined.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test {

    @Mock
    private Client client;

    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceImpl plannerService = new ServiceImpl();

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a way to avoid using an autowired constructor and just autowiring a field, however I use constructors as I consider it a good practice. It also makes it easy to inject a mocked object like so

```
@Mock
MyAction myAction;

MyApi myApi;
ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponseDto> testResponse = ResponseEntity.ok
                                                           (new AuthenticationResponseDto());


@Before
public void setup(){
   myApi = new MyApi(myAction);
}

@Test
public void simpleMyApiTestExample (){
  when(myAction.login(any())).thenAnswer(i-> testRespone);
  ResponseEntity<?> actualResponse = myApi.addAction(new MyDto());
  assertThat(actualResponse).isSameAs(testResponse);
}
```

Just to give you an idea. I just wrote this example in the SO text editor, so appologies for any typos/mistakes. But hopefully this shows why having constructors is useful for testing things that are autowired. It allows you to mock the objects necessary for instantiation by adding them to the constructor. In this example this would probably also apply to MyDto and AuthenticationResponseDto objects as well.